# Filling a table with key,value pairs

Tags: lua

I want to insert key,value pairs into a table

```
my_table = {}
for i=1, GetNumGroupMembers() do
    local unitID = "group"..i

    my_table.unitID = UnitName(unitID)
end

for key,value in pairs(my_table) do print(key,value) end
```

RESULT:

```
unitID group1
```

why is the key always `"unitID"` ? I need the VALUE of `unitID` as key, not the variable name

Comment: If the current answer helped you be sure to mark it as accepted so future users with the same problem can find their answer as well. Just check the shiny green checkmark next to their answer :D

Answer (score 5):

The key is always `unitID` because that's what you call it literally when doing

```
my_table.unitID = UnitName(unitID)
```

what you want to do is

```
my_table[unitID] = UnitName(unitID)
```

Which will use the value of the variable unitID as the key.